# SpriteKit time required for a node to drop

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am doing some tests with sprite kit and Xcode 6 and I am applying vertical impulse to a node. Can someone help me figure out how to calculate the time required for the node to drop to the ground (y = 0) considering the position of the node, the impulse vector value (vertical)? For example if my node is at y = 50 and I apply a vector value of (0,3) I need the time that will take for the node to lift up from the impulse and drop to y= 0. Also please take in mind I use physics world gravity of 3. I am not really good at physics nor math so if someone could guide me that would be really appreciated.

Comment: It requires an integration over time, so if you aren't good at math simply tweak the values until you get close to the desired time. With initial velocity vy=10 and gravity=-3 the y pos is as follows in each step: y += 7 => 7, y += 4 => 11, y += 1 => 12, y += -2 => 10, y += -5 => 5, y += -8 => -3. There's an integration function that you can write, for instance in Excel, that gives you these results for each step. BUT: whether the result in the physics engine will be 100% accurate is an entirely different matter and can depend on the framerate. Without sources it's a lot of guessing anyway.

Comment: hmm.. I don't really get what you mean but since there is no fixed formula for it I'll try to get a deeper look in physics. Thank you though for your reply

Comment: I meant to say there's no simple "y2 = y1 + velocity.y" formula because you have to integrate this over time, and time possibly meaning either fixed time steps or delta time, or both. Without the physics source code it's very hard to determine accurate results without actually running the simulation. Observing how it behaves with different values is likely to be easier than trying to calculate it in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to know the elapsed time?